# When I use SubScene my 3D models start to glitch. Any ideas why?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-3d

I am building an application that has 2 SubScenes, one for GUI and one for displaying 3D models (in my case OBJ).

For the import of the OBJ file I use the [ObjModelImporterJFX library by InteractiveMesh](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html).

Like the title says and as seen in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Er8D.jpg) the models start to glitch when they are handled by a SubScene. It seems like some covered parts that should not be visible are rendered like they were. Just for comparison [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYyYS.jpg) is how it looks normally, when the models are handled direcly by the scene.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);

        Group model = loadOBJ("course.obj");
        Group course = new Group(model);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

        Pane pane1 = new Pane(course);
        Pane pane2 = new Pane(root);

        SubScene subScene1 = new SubScene(pane1, 1000, 720);
        subScene1.setCamera(camera);

        SubScene subScene2 = new SubScene(pane2,500,500);

        borderPane.setLeft(subScene1);
        borderPane.setRight(subScene2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 1280,720, true);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    private Group loadOBJ(String fileName){

        URL url = getClass().getResource(fileName);

        Group modelRoot = new Group();

        ObjModelImporter importer = new ObjModelImporter();
        importer.read(url);

        for (MeshView view : importer.getImport()){
            modelRoot.getChildren().add(view);
        }

        return modelRoot;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I hope that someone has an idea why this is. Thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE:** To fix this enable [depthBuffer](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/SubScene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double,boolean,javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing)) by changing the constructor of the SubScene from

```
SubScene subScene1 = new SubScene(pane1, 1000, 720);
```

to

```
SubScene subScene1 = new SubScene(pane1, 1000, 720, true, null);
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`depth buffer`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/SubScene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double,boolean,javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing))?

Comment: @JoséPereda Thank you very much, this fixed it. Sorry I am new to javafx :)

Comment: When you have a problem, it's best to have a look at the documentation first thing.